# WMIprvse process leaks memory on 2008 server R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, wmi, wmi-query, wmi-service

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server running on a VM machine.
My .NET service is running on this server periodically querying WMI, for example:

SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Service WHERE ...

After a day or two WMIprvse  takes up to 500M memory and WMI queries start getting out of memory exceptions.

This article seems to be talking about this issue:
"http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958124"

I've seen other articles saying that Microsoft is aware of the problem and not going to issue a fix until the next major release.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/256eb40c-d050-4278-a3d8-863e30db02a0

I'd appreciate any suggestions and insights on this.

Answer (score 3):

Check out both the following KB articles,

- KB981314 - The "Win32_Service" WMI class leaks memory in Windows
  Server 2008 R2 and in Windows 7 -
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981314/en-us?p=1
- KB977357 - A memory leak issue occurs in the Windows Management
  Instrumentation service on a computer that is running Windows Server 
  2008 R2 or Windows 7 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977357

...but also worth noting we are on Windows 2008 R2 with SP1 (file versions higher than those provided by both hotfixes) and we are still seeing some slow memory leak issues possibly from either WMIAPSRV.exe and/or TRUSTEDINSTALLER.exe.

We are going to open a support call, if we find anything relevant will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hotfix available, but you have to request it by clicking on the link to request the hotfix at the top of the page.

[Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/981314?p=1)

Comment: This fixed my memory issue under a hyper-v vps.